# In flask should I ever redirect to the same route?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In flask should I ever redirect to the same route? FWIW the code below is the register route.
Also does flash messages work before redirects or render_template ?

Just to confirm, I think I can redirect to another route or  render_template without causing any errors. Is this correct?

Here is an example where I think why redirects to the same routes will cause an error.

I am using wtf forms.
In wtf forms I have a username + email + password + confirmation_password for the register routes forms.

```
@userinfo.route("/register", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    # if the value other then None, iow's you have a username in the database
    # The try is used if the database table User is empty. 
    if form.validate_on_submit():
    
        try:   
            all_usernames = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).all()
                flash ("The usesrname is already taken. Please select another username.")     
        except: 
            all_usernames = None        
                   
        finally:
            # do I want to redirect to register route?
            if all_usernames == forms_username:
                return redirect(url_for('userinfo.register')) 

    return render_template("register.html", title=register, form=form)
```

I can show the html but I don't think it is needed
Thanks.

Summary of browser steps.

step 1) I call the register function

step 2) Its starts off as a GET request and runs render_template because it skips form.validate_on_submit(). The register.html then runs.

step 3) I fill the information in the forms which username etc.

step 4) The POST request starts. This causes form.validate_on_submit() to run and all the code in between to run. Then instead of render_template I should redirect to a route. When I redirect I should get a GET request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirecting to the same route should not cause any problems.

But you need to know when to redirect to the same route. Redirecting to the same route after a POST request removes any data from the previous request. For example: if a user submitted a form and you want to show him a validation error you will not be able to, in this case you need to use `render_tempate()` instead.

In you example you will use `redirect()` if the registration was successful and there is not validation error, otherwise use `render_tempate()`

Comment: The reason I don't render_template at the end of the code in a POST request is because I am passing in variables in render_template? IOW's render_template is just when I want a GET request?



Can you give an example if one exists when I need redirect besides at the end of the route during a POST request and besides validation error? (Did I explain this question clearly to you?)

Thanks

Comment: I just want to clarify the line above should be "render_template is just when I have a GET request and am getting a POST request"

Comment: I did not get your question, can you clarify what are you trying to accomplish?